# ssh: Could not resolve hostname git: Name or service not known fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab

After I switched from HTTPS to SSH for my repo then I received this error when pushing to origin master:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I also add my ssh in the gitlab. What should I do?

Comment: How did you switch? Can you paste the command you used? This is probably a typo somewhere

Comment: I did this by : git remote add origin mySSH_url

Comment: Did you generate ssh key with default name, or custom? If custom, did you change then url formatting?

Comment: Can you post mySSH_url, unless it is secret? I still think you may have a typo there, perhaps wrong formatting or something

Comment: Try this git push <username>@<server address>:<path to git repository> master

Comment: I generate ssh key with default name!

Comment: No! mySSH_url is correct. I double check it.

Comment: If I want to do this:git push <username>@<server address>:<path to git repository> master, i will lose the advantage of SSH over HTTPS!

Comment: I got the same message for using a wrong syntax on my command line : `fetch --dry-run origin:$SHA` instead of `fetch --dry-run origin $SHA` .

Comment: Hope this would help someone :) In my case, I lost internet connectivity.

Comment: If this is inside a Docker container, try restarting the container.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I was getting the same error.

> This error typically occurs when there is an issue with the **SSH configuration** or the **Git remote** repository's hostname cannot be resolved.

Here, you can check your remote by running:

```
git remote -v
```

There are few reasons why this error occurs:

- Incorrect Hostname
- SSH Configuration
- Network Connection
- DNS Resolution
- Firewall or Proxy

Typically, you can solve this by Change the `[remote "origin"]` **URL** value in `.gitconfig` or `.config/git/config` file

Previously:

```
https://git@github.com:userName/repo.git
```

OR

```
ssh://git@github.com:userName/repo.git
```

New:

```
git@github.com:userName/repo.git
```

Answer (score 21):

HTTPS URLs provides an easy access to your repository, either private or public, even when you are working behind a firewall or proxy. And it is the recommended way.

On the other hand, SSH URLs use the secure ssh protocol in order to access a repository.

Coming back to your question, the error is likely because of improper configuration. The `git remote add` command is used to add a new remote to your repository, that you have already tried. However, switching from HTTPS to SSH url, means that your remote origin is already set to an http url and that you want to change.

Therefore, first check what url your current remote origin is referring to:

```
$ git remote -v
```

If it is referring to the HTTPS url, then you have to use

```
$ git remote set-url origin mySSH_url
```

command to change it to the SSH url.

Now, try `git remote -v`, it would display SSH urls configured for origin.

Do make sure that while working with SSH urls, you have generated and added the ssh key to the `ssh-agent` as well on GitLab/GitHub account.

[Here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) is a very good article on how to change a remote's url.

Also, you can learn more about which remote url to use [here](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/).

Comment: I try to delete the current HTTPS origin and then add a remote repository with SSH url. But I used your solution and it works too. thanks

Answer (score 16):

Well, in my case my local system was not connected to the VPN and hence was getting this error. So this could be one of the reasons apart from the above answers.

Comment: Actually, I am also working with VPN, `git fetch` not working in terminal but I can connect to the private bitbucket server in the browser.

Comment: Funny/sad such an easy solution is not coming right away to our heads. This was also the case for me right now.

Comment: The same thing! Reconnect to VPN resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue when working on azure.

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ssh.abc.azure.com: Temporary failure in name 
resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository 
exists.
```

**Reason:** This issue is due to the failure in WSL2.

**Fix:**
Disable and enable the WSL.

Comment: it worked for me after installing sdk man

Comment: I had to turn the computer off and on again (using WSL), error definitely related to WSL

Comment: Thanks. In my case, it's WSL issue. Usually getting this error every 2 months. I usually try with reconfiguring VPN, reboot the system. This time, I tried with restarting WSL service, it started working.

Answer (score 4):

While all the answers address the possibility of authentication failing with gitlab, the problem could also be DNS on your local system. For example:

```
$ ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.com
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.com: Name or service not known
$ ping gitlab.com
$ ping: gitlab.com: Name or service not known
```

This shows an issue with DNS settings on your computer. In RedHat, try this:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager
dnsmasq[2328]: nameserver 192.168.100.1 refused to do a recursive query
```

Oh my, that's a problem.

Is your network connection up?

```
$ ip a s
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:cd:c4:80:b8:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.7/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 86127sec preferred_lft 86127sec
    inet6 fe80::dd85:ef7b:1632:5975/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 

$ ip link
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:cd:c4:80:b8:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

For me, yes. Try restarting the connection:

```
$ sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 down
$ sudo ip link set dev wlp2s0 up
```

Now try running:

```
sudo systemctl status NetworkManager
```

And if the previous error went away, you can now ping gitlab.com.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for when you have upgraded from `WSL version 1 to version 2`.**

For some reason `github.com` can't be resolved once that update happens.
The issue has been raised against this [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285), there are also several solutions provided.
The once that worked for me are: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285#issuecomment-522201021
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285#issuecomment-532962762 -> modified version of the first solution

At step 3 you are asked to write to file `/etc/resolv.conf` which was tricky since it was a symbolic link. Following these [steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398053/1578758) resolved the writing problem

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a simple solution to a "dumb" problem:

After typing `$ git push`, I was prompted
`Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`, and instead of just hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>, actually writing "yes" and *then* hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I even got this error when cloning a repository from github, using `git clone https://github.com/user/repo`.
Now we have to use `git clone https://git@github.com/user/repo`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue on WSL2 doing that:

1. on wsl: open the `/etc/resolv.conf` and copy the servername auto-generated
2. on wsl: editing `/etc/wsl.conf` adding the follow code:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

3. close all wsl windows and on powershell run `wsl --shutdown`
4. open wsl terminal and create the file `/etc/resolv.conf` (it will not exists because it is not auto-generated anymore)
5. put into `/etc/resolv.conf` the follow content:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1 # cloudflare dns
nameserver 8.8.8.8 # google dns
nameserver PASTE_HERE_NAMESERVER_FROM_OLD_GENERATED_FILE # old dns generated by wsl
```

6. close all wsl windows and on powershell run `wsl --shutdown`
7. open wsl terminal and it should work now

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. It was something wrong with DNS server. The following command helped:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this error because I used backslashes "\" in the URL instead of slashes "/".

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when I was using `git push -u origin branchA`, but when I used the one recommend on bash `git push --set-upstream origin branchA` it worked out fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSL2 and WireGuard, turn off WireGuard while committing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

since the error says `Could not resolve hostname git` then its likely a dns problem and I usually have that problem with Ubuntu WSL

you can test it by pinging any website like google.com

```
ping google.com
```

to solve this problem add the lines bellow to your `(/etc/resolv.conf)` file

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

dont delete anything from the `(/etc/resolv.conf)` file, just add these lines at the end, and you may need to give it write permissions first.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
ssh-add <ssh-key-path>
```

Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

To Persian guys, who are using Shecan's DNS, I would have to say that, apparently, there's an issue with it. **Just disable it!**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, close my IDE completely and open it again to solve it